E-cash P2P instead Bitcoin?
I suggest change this Stack Exchange name from Bitcoin to Electronic Cash P2P or something like that. There are a lot of altcoins question already.

How does doing this improve the community at all? Few people are going to intuitively associate Electronic Cash P2P with bitcoin. Anyone who is in to a altcoin is going to associate it with bitcoin, as they are all derived from it. And the only way I see altcoins being utilized currently is as highly speculative instruments in exchanges. Bitcoin is barely adopted by vendors, there are only a handful which accept it here in Chicago, I doubt there are any businesses which accept .

My idea is transform this StackExchange in something more general. The inovation is on e-cash, not on Bitcoin per se. But for me is OK to keep Bitcoin, it was just a suggestion.

We've had renaming suggested at least twice already. :) See: • This site should be renamed, • Why is it bitcoin.SE instead of cryptocurrencies.SE, • the comments on this answer on Should this SE also cover questions about Ripple? and • Enlarge the scope to “cryptocurrency”, not just Bitcoin.

I think your suggestion would be a valid answer for This site should be renamed, though.

I don't think that "E-cash P2P" is particularly catchy, and find that Bitcoin is a pretty good descriptor for the main source of questions discussed on this SE.
I wouldn't mind it being more inclusive though, such as "Bitcoin and other cryptocurrencies" or similar.
